# Shopping cart component in Next.js is not re rendering on change, what am I overlooking?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, e-commerce

I am using Next.js 13.4.12 with TypeScript and the new app directory, trying to build an eCommerce site. For the shopping cart I decided to use localStorage, which should store just the product ID and quantity. My headless CMS is WordPress with WooCommerce.

The issue I am encountering is that the shopping cart does not re render when items are getting added or deleted. I need to close and open it again, so the changes are taking effect.

Less talk, more code!

This is the shopping cart component:

```
"use client";
import { useShoppingCart } from "../context/ShoppingCartContext";
import CartItem from "./cartItem";
import style from "./shoppingCart.module.css";
import {
  getProducts,
  getProduct,
} from "@/utils/wooCommerceApi";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

interface ShoppingCartProps {
  isOpen: boolean;
}

export default function ShoppingCart({
  isOpen,
}: ShoppingCartProps) {
  const { closeCart, cartItems } = useShoppingCart();
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<any>([]);

  // Fetch product data for each item in the cart, so the data
  // can be passed into the CartItem component and calculate the sum of the cart
  useEffect(() => {
    const productIds = new Set();
    const fetchedProducts: any = [];

    // Fetch product data
    const fetchProduct = async (
      id: number,
      quantity: number
    ) => {
      const productData = await getProduct(id);
      fetchedProducts.push({
        ...productData,
        quantity: quantity,
      });
    };

    // Iterate and check if product data has already been fetched
    cartItems.forEach((item) => {
      if (!productIds.has(item.id)) {
        fetchProduct(item.id, item.quantity);
        productIds.add(item.id);
      }
    });

    // Add fetched product data to state
    setProducts(fetchedProducts);
  }, [cartItems]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: isOpen ? "flex" : "none",
      }}
      className={style.cartWrapper}
    >
      <div className={style.cartClose}>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="32"
          height="32"
          fill="#000000"
          viewBox="0 0 256 256"
          onClick={closeCart}
        >
          <path d="M165.66,101.66,139.31,128l26.35,26.34a8,8,0,0,1-11.32,11.32L128,139.31l-26.34,26.35a8,8,0,0,1-11.32-11.32L116.69,128,90.34,101.66a8,8,0,0,1,11.32-11.32L128,116.69l26.34-26.35a8,8,0,0,1,11.32,11.32ZM232,128A104,104,0,1,1,128,24,104.11,104.11,0,0,1,232,128Zm-16,0a88,88,0,1,0-88,88A88.1,88.1,0,0,0,216,128Z"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div className={style.cartContent}>
        {products.map((product: any) => (
          <CartItem
            key={product.id}
            id={product.id}
            quantity={product.quantity}
            name={product.name}
            price={product.price}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className={style.cartTotal}>
        Total:
        {products.length > 0
          ? products.reduce(
              (total: number, product: any) => {
                return (
                  total +
                  Number(product.price) * product.quantity
                );
              },
              0
            )
          : null}
      </div>
      <div className={style.cartFooter}>
        <Link href="/checkout" onClick={closeCart}>
          Checkout
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the cart items component:

```
"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import style from "./cartItem.module.css";
import { useShoppingCart } from "../context/ShoppingCartContext";

interface CartItemProps {
  quantity: number;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  // image:string;
  // alt:string;
}

export default function CartItem({
  id,
  name,
  price,
}: CartItemProps) {
  const { removeFromCart } = useShoppingCart();

  return (
    <div className={style.itemWrapper}>
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <div className={style.price}>{price} ISK</div>
      <button onClick={() => removeFromCart(id)}>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="32"
          height="32"
          fill="#000000"
          viewBox="0 0 256 256"
        >
          <path d="M205.66,194.34a8,8,0,0,1-11.32,11.32L128,139.31,61.66,205.66a8,8,0,0,1-11.32-11.32L116.69,128,50.34,61.66A8,8,0,0,1,61.66,50.34L128,116.69l66.34-66.35a8,8,0,0,1,11.32,11.32L139.31,128Z"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the shopping cart context:

```
'use client';
import { createContext, useContext, ReactNode, useState } from 'react';
import ShoppingCart from '../shoppingCart/shoppingCart';
import { useLocalStorage } from '../hooks/useLocalStorage';

interface ShoppingCartProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

interface ShoppingCartContext {
  getItemQuantity: (id: number) => number;
  increaseCartQuantity: (id: number) => void;
  decreaseCartQuantity: (id: number) => void;
  removeFromCart: (id: number) => void;
  openCart: () => void;
  closeCart: () => void;
  cartQuantity: number;
  cartItems: CartItem[];
}

interface CartItem {
  id: number;
  quantity: number;
}

const ShoppingCartContext = createContext({} as ShoppingCartContext);

export function useShoppingCart() {
  return useContext(ShoppingCartContext);
}

export function ShoppingCartProvider({ children }: ShoppingCartProviderProps) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useLocalStorage<CartItem[]>(
    'shopping-cart',
    []
  );

  const openCart = () => setIsOpen(true);
  const closeCart = () => setIsOpen(false);

  // counting all the items in the cart and returning the total
  const cartQuantity = (cartItems || []).reduce(
    (quantity: any, item: any) => item.quantity + quantity,
    0
  );

  function getItemQuantity(id: number) {
    return (
      ((cartItems || []).find((item: CartItem) => item.id === id) as CartItem | undefined)?.quantity || 0
    );
  }
  

  function increaseCartQuantity(id: number) {
    setCartItems((currentItems) => {
      if (currentItems.find((item: any) => item.id === id) == null) {
        return [...currentItems, { id, quantity: 1 }];
      } else {
        return currentItems.map((item: any) => {
          if (item.id === id) {
            return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 };
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  function decreaseCartQuantity(id: number) {
    setCartItems((currentItems) => {
      if (currentItems.find((item: any) => item.id === id)?.quantity == 1) {
        return currentItems.filter((item: any) => item.id !== id);
      } else {
        return currentItems.map((item: any) => {
          if (item.id === id) {
            return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity - 1 };
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  function removeFromCart(id: number) {
    setCartItems((currentItems) => {
      return currentItems.filter((item: any) => item.id !== id);
    });
  }

  return (
    <ShoppingCartContext.Provider
      value={{
        getItemQuantity,
        increaseCartQuantity,
        decreaseCartQuantity,
        removeFromCart,
        cartItems,
        cartQuantity,
        openCart,
        closeCart,
      }}
    >
      {children}
      <ShoppingCart isOpen={isOpen} />
    </ShoppingCartContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The data gets store immediately in the localStorage, so this seems to be running completely fine. I have been testing like wild and was able to see, that the shopping cart component does not re render after the changes have been done to the cartItems.

Just let me know if you need more info to clarify things. Highly appreciate any help coming in.